# Removing rows in dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in python, lets call it df:

```
# import module
import pandas as pd

# assign data
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration 1': [5,7,3,10,17,13],
                   'duration 2': [3,9,9,11,34,10],
                   'name': ['John','Sue','Chris','Joey','Robert','Mike'],
                   'duration 3': [6,14,7,10,17,13],
                   'duration 4': [8,9,12,11,13,12],})
```

I want to remove or filter rows out based on 2 conditions being met, for example:
if 'duration 2' - 'duration 1' < 0 and 'duration 4' - 'duration 3' < 0 remove row

I just can't seem to get the logic to work, where am I going wrong. It seems I can do one or the other but not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
cond=(df['duration 2']-df['duration 1']).lt(0) & (df['duration 4']-df['duration 3']).lt(0)
```

Finally:

```
df[~cond]
```

output:

```
   duration 1   duration 2  name    duration 3  duration 4
0   5               3       John        6           8
1   7               9       Sue         14          9
2   3               9       Chris       7           12
3   10              11      Joey        10          11
4   17              34      Robert      17          13
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I did have to change it to .le instead of .lt because I didn't realize I had results that came out at 0.